# R Dplyr; calculating difference between two columns from previous row but putting result in next row without for loop

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to solve the following problem in which I am looking to calculate the difference between two columns from the previous row on the next row using dplyr in R, preferably without the use of a loop. In this specific example, I want to calculate r_j - s_j from the previous row but then paste the result in the next row.

Here is some sample data:

```
require(tidyverse)
data = tibble(LM = c(100, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 1300), s_j = c(2,2,2,1,2,2,1,1)) %>% 
       bind_cols(,r_j = rep(25, nrow(.))

     LM   s_j   r_j
1   100     2    25
2   300     2    25
3   400     2    25
4   500     1    25
5   600     2    25
6   700     2    25
7   800     1    25
8  1300     1    25
```

My desired output is this;

```
     LM   s_j   r_j
1   100     2    25
2   300     2    23
3   400     2    21
4   500     1    19
5   600     2    18
6   700     2    16
7   800     1    14
8  1300     1    13
```

A solution to this problem is:

```
for (k in 2:nrow(data)){ 
   tmp = data$r_j[k-1] - data$s_j[k-1]
   data$r_j[k] = tmp 
}
```

which yields

```
     LM   s_j   r_j
1   100     2    25
2   300     2    23
3   400     2    21
4   500     1    19
5   600     2    18
6   700     2    16
7   800     1    14
8  1300     1    13
```

but surely there exists a much better solution than the for loop in R? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use `lag()` like this:  `data %>% mutate(new_value = lag(r_j)-lag(s_j))`

Comment: @Jrakru56 Not quite what I am looking for; sorry I should have been more clear in the statement of the problem. I want the cumulative difference over the rows, so that basically (r_j - s_j) from the previous row is pasted in the next row, and then this result serves as r_j for the next calculation of (r_j - s_j), and so on. The first entry in the column r_j should therefore (ideally) be left untouched.

Comment: you are right! I just read the description and not the code. I actually don't know how to do this.  Using `dplyr` and `lag` will not work even  if I did something like this `data %>%  mutate(r_j = (ifelse(is.na(lag(r_j)),r_j, lag(r_j))) - (ifelse(is.na(lag(s_j)),0, lag(s_j)))) `. My best guess is your code work because you assign during every iteration of the loop but using `mutate` takes a copy of the object, applies `lag` and does not create a rolling difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to generate the cumulative sum of s_j and then subtract that from r_j

```
data %>% mutate(
    temp = cumsum(s_j),
    r_j2 = r_j-temp
)
# A tibble: 8 x 5
     LM   s_j   r_j  temp  r_j2
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   100     2    25     2    23
2   300     2    25     4    21
3   400     2    25     6    19
4   500     1    25     7    18
5   600     2    25     9    16
6   700     2    25    11    14
7   800     1    25    12    13
8  1300     1    25    13    12
```

**EDIT:** To generate the exact output desired one can subtract the value of s_j from its cumsum and get the following:

```
data %>% mutate(
     temp = cumsum(s_j)-s_j,
     r_j2 = r_j-temp
 )
# A tibble: 8 x 5
     LM   s_j   r_j  temp  r_j2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   100     2    25     0    25
2   300     2    25     2    23
3   400     2    25     4    21
4   500     1    25     6    19
5   600     2    25     7    18
6   700     2    25     9    16
7   800     1    25    11    14
8  1300     1    25    12    13
```

**EDIT2:** Including the solution by IceCreamToucan which does not need to generate a temp column:

```
data %>% mutate(
     r_j2 = coalesce(lag(r_j - cumsum(s_j)), r_j)
     )
# A tibble: 8 x 4
     LM   s_j   r_j  r_j2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   100     2    25    25
2   300     2    25    23
3   400     2    25    21
4   500     1    25    19
5   600     2    25    18
6   700     2    25    16
7   800     1    25    14
8  1300     1    25    13
```

Comment: @IceCreamToucan oh that is also a nice way of doing it. I'll add that solution as well. I did update my answer to get the desired output but I will also include your solution.

Comment: @Baraliuh Wouldn't this solution solve the special case where there is an initial value? I don't think it would work if r_j was a random variable.

Comment: @Jrakru56 I'm not sure that I understand your question. I have made a couple of edits to the post. Do you still see the error you describe?  If so, could you try to clarify it?